# Create a matrix with alternate rows from two matrices [MATLAB]

Tags: matlab, sorting, if-statement, matrix

I have the following question:

> Write a program that:
>
> > 1. Starts by requesting an A matrix by keyboard.
> > 2. Next, if the number of columns of A is odd, the last column of additional zeros must be added. From this moment matrix, A has an even number (n) of columns.

The program will divide the input matrix into two sub-matrices.

> > 3. The first sub-matrix (A1) contains the first n / 2 columns of A. The second sub-matrix (A2) has the last n / 2 columns.
> > 4. **Finally, the program must calculate and write on the screen a matrix B that has the rows of A1 in the odd rows and those of A2 in the pairs.**

### Example code

```
A = input('Enter a matrix:')
% A = magic(5) % for example
[filA, colA] = size(A);

if rem(colA,2)==1
    A = [A, zeros(filA,1)]
    colA = colA + 1;
end

A1 = A(:, [1:colA/2])
A2 = A(:, [1+(colA/2):colA])

%B
```

Comment: ..and the question is how to outsource "homework"? Or ...where did I hide the errorcode and effort in resolving it? Restructure your question if its not homework.. it reads like it and implement the error your code produces and structure your question around the problem.

Comment: Please clarify your question. What is the problem with your code? Is there an error? What do you expect to get from posting your code here?

Comment: I do not know how to use the if statement to create the matrix B, taking the rows of matrices A1 and A2 alternately. That's what the code lacks. Thanks

Comment: Now I have tried to restructure the problem, making emphasis in step 4, in the first version I had tried to give my solution to step 4, but I did not know how to handle rows of each matrix to be able to concatenate in my matrix B.

Comment: There is no branching here (if statements). What have you actually attempted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution I propose you:

```
A = [1 2 3; 1 2 3; 1 2 3; 1 2 3];
[A_r,A_c] = size(A);

if (mod(A_c,2) ~= 0)
    A = [A zeros(A_r,1)];
    A_c = A_c + 1;
end

off = A_c / 2;
A1 = A(:,1:off);
A2 = A(:,(off+1):A_c);

B = reshape([A1(:) A2(:)].',2*A_r,[])
```

It makes use of the [reshape function](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html) for interleaving the rows of the matrices `A1` and `A2`. By omitting the `;` at the end of the last line, you let Matlab print the output of the final computation in the console, which is:

```
B =
     1     2
     3     0
     1     2
     3     0
     1     2
     3     0
     1     2
     3     0
```

Using a step by step debugging approach, you can see how every step is being performed.

Comment: Only one nitpick: `[A1(:) A2(:)]` is just `A`, after the column of zeros. You don't need to compute `A1` and `A2` explicitly at all.

Comment: Nice, Now I running your program. I testing for any matrix of any dimesion.

Comment: @MadPhysicist I don't get your first comment, can you explain me? :O

Comment: I forgot the `(:)`. Whoops.

Comment: Wait tho, `[A1(:) A2(:)]` is the same as `reshape(A, [], 2)`, so it's not necessary to compute the intermediate results. In fact, with lazy copying it also saves time and space.

Comment: you can remove the 3 lines starting with `off =`, `A1 =`, `A2 =` and just make the last line as `B = reshape(reshape(A, [], 2).',2*A_r,[])`.

Answer (score 0):

### My solution

```
clear all, clc;
A = input('Ingrese una matriz:')
[filA, colA] = size(A);
if rem(colA,2)==1
    A = [A, zeros(filA,1)]
    colA = colA + 1;
end

A1 = A(:, [1:colA/2])
A2 = A(:, [1+(colA/2):colA])

B = A2([1;1]*(1:size(A2,1)),:)
B(1:2:end,:) = A1
```

Comment: However, it seems that there are still some errors in step 4 since I run your code and I find elements in matrix B might be wrong. @Oromion

Comment: 10 hours ago, I runned the code and generated error about dimension, later the program worked fine. I don't know. I tried in Octave 4.2.1

Comment: Well, maybe I misunderstand the step 4, but I updated my posts and you can have a quick view of it. @Oromion